# android: To check whether textfile exists on google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am integrating Drive within my app. 
I am able to upload and download file from Drive.

But the issue is, I am not able to identify the particular textfile exists on drive or not, when I do first time uploading.

Please some one help me with accurate solution.

Thank you

Comment: First learn to ask a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters)

A sample query can be built as below and we can check if the file already exists or not

```
class SearchFileTask extends AsyncTask<Query, Void, MetadataBufferResult>{
    @Override
    protected MetadataBufferResult doInBackground(Query... params) {
        return Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), params[0]).await();
}

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult) {
       if(metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer().getCount()==0)
           // NO file
       else
           // File exists with given name
    }
}

Query query = new Query
        .Builder()
                .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "filename.extension"))
                .build();
new SearchFileTask().execute(query);
```

Comment: @AlpsRana glad I could help (: !!

Comment: Unfortunately, when I copied that code into Android Studio it warned me that [DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult). MetadataBuffer is returned directly in the new Drive clients. Please refer to [Querying for files](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries) for more information.